# Struggling with a Calculus III problem :$\iint x+y\ dS,$ where $S(u,v)=2\cos(u)\vec i+2\sin(u)\vec j+v \vec k$ and $0\le u\le \pi/2;\;0 \le v \le9.$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

So I have had Calc III many moons ago but I cannot seem to solve this problem for my son who is taking it now.  Worked it four ways and got four different answers.  Hoping someone here can set me right.

Problem: Solve     $\iint f(x,y)\,dS,$ where

$$f(x,y) = x + y$$ and
$$S(u,v) = 2\cos(u)\vec i + 2\sin(u)\vec j + v \vec k$$
$$0\le u \le \pi/2;\;0 \le v \le 9. $$

My solution is:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial u} = -2\sin(u) \vec i + 2\cos(u) \vec j$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial v} = \vec k$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial S}{\partial v} = 2\cos(u) \vec i - 2 \sin(u) \vec j $$
$$\left\lvert\frac{\partial S}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial S}{\partial v} \right\rvert = \sqrt{4\cos^2(u) + 4 \sin^2(u)}=2$$
$$\iint(x+y)\,dS =\iint(x+y)2\,dA$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^2_0(r\cos\theta +r\sin\theta) 2r\,dr\,d\theta =$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^2_02r^2(\cos\theta +\sin\theta) \,dr\,d\theta =$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0(16/3)(\cos\theta +\sin\theta) \,d\theta =$$
$$32/3.$$

His online program doesn’t like this answer.  I got the same answer by staying in rectangular coordinates.  Feel like I’m setting something up wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should not integrate over $r$ as $r$ is constant $2$ on your surface. In fact, $dS = 2du dv$.

Comment: It is necessary to state over what region an integral is taken. I suspect you mean for your integral to be taken over the surface you call S. Is that right?

Comment: Well S is the surface.  The book shows integration going over the projection of S on the x,y plane.

Comment: Note that the surface S is one-quarter (90º) of a right cylinder of radius = 2 and height = 9, whose axis is the z-axis. It lies over a quarter-circle in the xy-plane. The integrand x + y does not depend on z. So the answer should be 9 times a certain integral over that quarter-circle in the plane.

Comment: That makes sense that $dS = 2 dudv$. So should I substitute $2cos(u) and 2sin(u) for x and y?

Comment: Dan I agree that it’s a quarter cylinder.  When I did that integration I got 32/3.

Comment: The answer is 72.  Achille’s comment led me to the right answer.